# How can I get a text message sent from myself, to myself, to sound an alert?

Tags: messages, reminders

I am scheduling texts to myself to make absolutely certain I don't miss certain meetings.  The Reminders app is way too subtle, but a text message with a custom text tone, would work great.

The trouble is, automating a text with a calendar alert works but always sends as me, to me.  Which means no sound is triggered.  I've even set my custom text tone and it doesn't matter, no sound will ever trigger.

Is there any way to have a text message sent in Messages from my mac, to my phone, trigger a sound on the phone?

Comment: This used to work for me in an earlier iOS. I used it to get messages from my raspberry pi automations and I had a custom notification sound. I'm wondering if it was my iOS 16 update that silenced them or if it was something else. Have you managed to figure this out?

Comment: I just spoke with Apple support and immediately got frustrated and gave up. What version of iOS are you on?

Comment: I thought I was onto something. I found the mentions, notify me setting and tried sending myself a message with my name in it, and the first time I tried it, it worked. I heard my notification text tone and the message appeared in a banner at the top. However, every subsequent attempt failed. Ugh.

Comment: Sadly, I never got anywhere with this and gave it up.

Comment: I got a tiny bit closer to a workaround. I created a personal automation in the shortcuts app. "When I get a message from <my contact card>..."... The action doesn't really matter because it won't run automatically and as far as I know, there's not a way to show a notification with the content of the message.  But simply having the trigger & any arbitrary action will trigger a shortcuts notification, which I would simply note means I got a message from myself - so I'll know to look at my self-to-self message thread. Crappy workaround, but it's something. Tested it from my computer & it works.